# String converted JSON Object is not proper while using JSONArray.put(JSONObject)

Tags: java, json, string

```java
String dummyStr="[{\"Emp_Id\":\"1254\",\"Emp_Name\":\"abcd\"},{\"Emp_Id\":\"1234\",\"Emp_Name\":\"efgh\"}]";

System.out.println("The JSON string is"+dummyStr);
```

**IS GIVING THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT:**

> The JSON string is[{"Emp_Id":"1254","Emp_Name":"abcd"},{"Emp_Id":"1234","Emp_Name":"efgh"}]

****But when i try to put into an arraylist it is displaying as ****

```java
tmpJsonArrayList.put(dummyStr)

System.out.println("The JSON string  List  is"+tmpJsonArrayList);
```

> The JSON string  List  is["[{\"Emp_Id\":\"1254\",\"Emp_Name\":\"abcd\"},{\"Emp_Id\":\"1234\",\"Emp_Name\":\"efgh\"}]"]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more what you are trying to achieve? Also a little bit more code could be helpful. What kind of list is tmpJsonArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use JsonParser to convert the string to json array:

```
    String dummyStr="[{\"Emp_Id\":\"1254\",\"Emp_Name\":\"abcd\"},{\"Emp_Id\":\"1234\",\"Emp_Name\":\"efgh\"}]";

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    // parse the string as JsonArray
    JsonArray tmpJsonArrayList = (JsonArray) parser.parse(dummyStr);


    System.out.println("The JSON string List is"+tmpJsonArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dummyStr="[{\"Emp_Id\":\"1254\",\"Emp_Name\":\"abcd\"},{\"Emp_Id\":\"1234\",\"Emp_Name\":\"efgh\"}]";

JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(dummyStr);
JsonArray tmpJsonArrayList = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
System.out.println("The JSON string List is"+tmpJsonArrayList);
```

This is how we can parse json string in java. You will need to add `com.google.gson` library to compile this code.